# Почему не загружается реусрс с помощью Resources.Load, а возвращает null?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В моем проекте я использую большое количество спрайтов. Все спрайты, которые я хочу загружать с помощью C# скрипта лежат в папке `Assets/Sprites`

В доках описание

```
public static function Load(path: string): Object;
public static function Load(path: string, systemTypeInstance: Type): Object;
```

где `path` - путь до конечной папки.

Я пробую тестировать загрузку:

```
Sprite myFruit = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Graphics_3");
```

Но `myFruit` почему-то имеет значение `null`.
Почему не загружается ресурс? И как это сделать?

---

<sub>Вопрос из https://stackoverflow.com/q/24977986/6104996</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Resources.Load` ищет директорию в папке `Assets/Resources`.  То есть для складирования ресурсов нужно принудительно создать папку `Resources` в корне проекта (в папке `Assets`) и уже туда класть все необходимые ресурсы.

Если вы хотите брать ресурсы спрайтов из папки `Sprites`, то нужно эту папку создать в ресурсах, т.е. `Assets/Resources/Sprites`.

И тогда вы можете уже спокойно загружать их так:

```
Sprite myFruit = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Graphics_3");
```

То есть указывать `Assets/Resources` уже не обязательно, а  `path` в функции `Load` является путем относительно именно данной папки, а не проекта в целом.

Также убедитесь в том, что ваша картинка имеет тип *Sprite*

А также, если вы хотите загрузить мультиспрайт, то используйте `LoadAll`:

```
Sprite[] myFruit = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites/Graphics_3");
```

Пример загрузки текстур

```
Texture2D[] iconTextures;

function LoadAllIconTextures() {         
     var array = Resources.LoadAll("PropIcons", typeof(Texture2D))
     iconTextures = new Texture2D[array.length];
     for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
         iconTextures[i] = array[i] as Texture2D;
}
```

---

<sub>Ответ переведен с дополнением с https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978085/6104996</sub>